# Extract distinct row values from a sheet to another sheet based on max dates per unique rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I want to extract rows based on max date or max B per unique values of col A and col c. Doesn't matter if it is vba or excel formula. Help please.

**Old Sheet**
[image]

**New Sheet**
[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTmiR.png)

Comment: It is very complicated. If you have enough Excel knowledge this YouTube tutorial should give you direction https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qICltTRvEbE

Comment: Anyone who is willing to help? D:

Comment: Have you watched the above video?

Comment: Its working now.. Thanks a lot @Yisroel Tech

Comment: I'll consider this as a solved Q. @iHateBugs , would you mind sharing the solutions here.. ? It'll help removing this question from the unanswered list (and help others too.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**You can find the solution / answer here :** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qICltTRvEbE

Comment: Answers like this tend to get useless as soon as the link breaks, so it is preferred to summarise the solution in the answer so that the core idea is still present even though the external source might not anymore be available. Please have a look at the [How do I write a good answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) page in the help center.